# Sublime Text: Regular Expression to Remove Lines NOT Starting With

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text to edit a batch file on Windows. I'd like to remove all of the lines that do *not* begin with `ECHO` or `REM`. I figure this must be possible with regular expressions, but I can't figure it out. Anybody?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From what I can understand, Sublime Text uses Python's regex engine.

This code matches all lines that don't begin with `ECHO` and `REM`:

```
^(?!(?:ECHO|REM)).*\s*
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this won't match the last line because it wouldn't end with a `\n`.

Comment: @QuickJoeSmith: Yep, it might be easier to just get rid of the the line ending.

Comment: Somewhat related: You can enable `"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true` in Sublime's config to make sure files end with a newline upon saving. Might help here. This setting comes in handy when editing C/C++ source files.

Comment: @j.w.r: Thanks, I never knew about that option. I'll make sure to enable it.

Comment: @Blender Thanks very much for the quick answer! My batch files tend to end with a blank line anyway, so, in my case, your original answer works very well. Thanks again! `^(?!(?:ECHO|REM)).*\n`

Comment: @MarceloFilho: That regex is malformed, you're not terminating `(.`. Also, specify non-capturing groups with `(?:...)` so you don't just select the entire line.